# Debugging within visual studio code - sourcemap

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, source-maps

I am trying to setup the launch configuration/'sourceMapPathOverrides' within VS code, to debug my components/script files. However I do not seem to get it working (Breakpoints are unbound).

---

I have searched for the correct configuration or explanation on the sourceMapPathOverrides, however without any success. Multiple blogs/SO questions had their own launch.json files, specific for their own solutions (but none of these are working for me).

Neither could I find any good explanation on how I can configure these sourceMapPathOverrides. What I did find though, is the .scripts command for the debug console. This shows me a clue, but I do not get how to use that hint, to correctly setup the overrides.

```
This breakpoint was initially set in:
C:\repos\<applicationname>\src\app\components\<Component>.vue

We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name:
C:\repos\<applicationname>\js\webpack:\<applicationalias>\src\app\components\<Component>.vue
```

Where the application alias contains of a name with a slash like: name\application-short-name.
So the actual corresponding source location looks as following

```
C:\repos\<applicationname>\js\webpack:\name\application-short-name\src\app\components\<Component>.vue
```

---

Hopefully anyone can either point me in the correct direction or explain how these overrides work/should be configured